He verificado la lògica de mi condiciòn y parece estar correcta, pero la palabra "Perdiste" no se imprime en pantalla ¿Alguna idea para solucionar?
Estoy trabajando en un juego de palabras donde el jugador debe adivinar la palabra correcta, tiene 6 intentos, al terminar los intentos debería imprimir en la consola perdiste, pero si embargo no sale esa opciòn, mi lògica del juego funciona correctamente solo tiene ese pequeño error
Este seria mi codigo
if (INTENTO === palabra){
ERROR.style.display = "none"
terminar("<h1>GANASTE!</h1>")
return

if(intentos==0){
    terminar("<h1>PERDISTE</h1>")
}


y después del return no falta un } que cierre el primer if???

y de casualidad no sale algun error en la consola???

El if que imprimiría la palabra perdiste está dentro del bloque de código que se ejecuta solo si se cumple la condición del primer if.
No lo puedes visualizar fácilmente, pues tu indentación está mal. Corrígiendola, quedaría algo como:
if (INTENTO === palabra) {
  ERROR.style.display = "none"
  terminar("<h1>GANASTE!</h1>")
  return

  if(intentos==0){
    terminar("<h1>PERDISTE</h1>")
  }

Espero que lo puedas visualizar más fácilmente ahora. También puedes observar que también falta la llave de cierre del bloque.
A partir de este punto, solo sabiendo lo que buscas se podría responder puntualmente, pero imaginando la lógica del juego, es de suponer que tu realmente quieres evaluar el segundo if solo si no se cumplió el primero o bien independientemente de este. Lo correcto en estos casos sería algo como:
if (INTENTO === palabra) {
  ERROR.style.display = "none"
  terminar("<h1>GANASTE!</h1>")
  return
} else if(intentos==0) {
  terminar("<h1>PERDISTE</h1>")
}

O:
if (INTENTO === palabra) {
  ERROR.style.display = "none"
  terminar("<h1>GANASTE!</h1>")
  return
} 
if(intentos==0) {
  terminar("<h1>PERDISTE</h1>")
}

Respectivamente.
No me canso de insistir a todo mundo que la indentación es un aspecto importante de la programación, y que su único objetivo es hacer que la estructura del programa sea más fácil de comprender para nosotros, los humanos. La computadora no necesita ni espacios ni líneas, puedes darle todo el programa en una sola línea, que igual va a poder interpretarlo correctamente.
